# Search for 7 previous elements from the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my current code. I have a bit of trouble with fetching the previous elements from the list using with the value.

When I have the list that show like this:

```
 ['407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD', '409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK']
```

I want to go back to the 7 previous elements before the `407 Sky Sports F1` which show like this:

```
 ['108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ']
```

Then to this when I use to call PageUP function again:

```
['101 BBC One S East', '102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living']
```

On my code, when I use to call the PageUp function, it will fetch the elements from the list using with `self.channels_Index` value as `0` which the value should be `7` so I have removed the value `0` but it will not fetch the 7 previous elements from the list.

Here is the code:

```
def PageUp(self):
    if not channel == self.channel[0]:
       program_id = list()

       if int(self.channels_Index) == 7:
          self.channels_Index = 0
          end_index = self.channels_Index + 7
       else:
          self.channels_Index -= 14
          end_index = self.channels_Index + 7

       if end_index > len(self.channel):
          end_index -= len(self.channel) - end_index
       channels_list = self.channel[self.channels_Index:end_index]

       if self.channels_Index > len(self.channel):
          self.channels_Index -= 7
       print "channels_list"
       print (channels_list)
```

Here is the list for self.channel:

```
 ['101 BBC One S East', '102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living', '108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ', '407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD', '409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK', '414 Eurosport 2 UK', '415 BT Sport 1', '416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV', '421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']
```

What I am expecting to do is when I have the 7 elements from the list that show like this:

```
 ['416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV', '421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']
```

When I call the PageUp function, I want to fetch the 7 previous elements from the list:

```
 ['409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK', '414 Eurosport 2 UK', '415 BT Sport 1']
```

When I call the PageUp function again, I want to fetch the 7 previous elements:

```
 ['402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ', '407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD']
```

Can you please show me an example how I can fetch the 7 previous elements from the list in each time when I call the PageUp function?

Comment: You will have to watch boundries, but given an index into a list, you can get the 7 previous entries with x[-7:index].

Comment: Could you please give more context, like the class itself, etc?

Comment: It might be a better design to make the `pageUp()` method just set the index to (current - 7), then have a separate method to display the list at the current index.

Comment: @bigmacd which line i need to make the change on?

Comment: @bigmacd `x[-7:index]` will grab items starting at the seventh-to-last, but that isn't what he wants; he wants the seven items before the "current" index, which aren't necessarily the final seven items.  Also, if the index-th position is earlier in the list than seventh-to-last, then that expression will return an empty slice.

Comment: I didn't define "index", that was left up to him.

Comment: I think you meant `x[index-7:index]`.

Comment: at the end of the list the self.channels_Index will show `28` and end_Index will show `35`

Comment: @JohnGordon yes you are correct. Can you post the code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def PageUp(self):
    self.channels_Index = max(self.channels_Index -7), 0)
    channels_list = self.channel[self.channels_Index):min(len(self.channel), self.channels_Index + 7)]
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, but it show the same as my current code show. Any idea? :(

Comment: I have changed some of the code and i can see it is working perfect. Thank you so much for this as the problem are now solved!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to break things up a little more to make it easier. For example, if you include a setter for the channel_index and make a constraint that is can't be set negative. I think below might be an example of an easier solution

```
class IAmAssumingThisIsForATVGuideOrSomething:

    channels = ['101 BBC One S East',
                '102 BBC Two',
                '103 ITV',
                '104 Channel 4',
                '105 Channel 5',
                '106 Sky One',
                '107 Sky Living',
                '108 Sky Atlantic',
                '401 Sky Sports 1 UK',
                '402 SKY Sports 2 UK',
                '403 Sky Sports 3 UK',
                '404 Sky Sports 4 UK']

    def __init__(self):
        self._current_index = 0

    @property
    def current_channel(self):
        return self.channels[self.current_index]

    @property
    def current_index(self):
        return self._current_index

    @current_index.setter
    def current_index(self, value):
        '''
        Using the setter will make sure your
        index doesn't get set negative
        '''
        if value < 0:
            self._current_index = 0
        else:
            self._current_index = value

    def page_up(self):
        self.current_index -= 7
        return self.channels[self.current_index: self.current_index + 7]
```